# OAuth2Strategy requires a authorizationURL option

Tags: oauth-2.0, nestjs, authorization, google-oauth

```
[Nest] 8860  - 13/01/2023, 11:50:03 am   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] OAuth2Strategy requires a authorizationURL option
TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a authorizationURL option
    at new OAuth2Strategy
```

google strategy :

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { Profile } from "passport";
import { VerifyCallback, Strategy } from "passport-oauth2";

@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor() {
        super({
            clientID: "clientId",
            clientSecret: "clientSecret",
            callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/google/callback",
            scope: ["email", "profile"]
        })
    }

    async validate(accessToken: string, refresToken: string, profile: Profile, done: VerifyCallback) {
      done(null,profile);
    }
}
```

where can i get authorizationURL and tokenURL ?
im getting this error while using passport-oauth2 this package but after using passport-google-oauth20 package this error is gone.

after using passport-google-oauth20 im getting a new error after hitting http://localhost:3000/google route which is :

```
[Nest] 8608  - 13/01/2023, 11:58:43 am   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Failed to obtain access token
InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain access token
```

how to solve this ?